# Azure Databricks to S3 - transfer large data - performance issues

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

We have to move 800 millions records from Azure Databricks to S3. I have started testing with small data set.

In below code I am iterating over DataFrame and splitting into 200K records per file.
For 1 million records - when I pushed data into single file then it finished within  60 seconds but when I am trying to move those records into 5 files (200K each) then its taking 20-25 minutes. This is not going to work for large set of data. Is there any better approach to push large set of data from Azure Databricks to S3?

Below code (to push 1 million records into 1 file) took around 1 min:

```
from boto3.session import Session
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import requests
import boto3

file_name = 'full_data_in_one_file.csv'

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
s3_client.put_object(Body=df.toPandas().to_csv(index=False), Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
```

Below Code took around 27 minutes (when writing into multiple files 200k records per file).
**Note** - It takes long time between 2 files as data size keep increasing. This code wont work for 800 millions records.

```
from boto3.session import Session
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import requests
import boto3
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import random
import time


# Create connetion with AWS S3 bucket
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

# Read Data from table as json file
df = spark.read.format("json").options(header='true', inferSchema='true').option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").load("abfss://path/product.db/table_name")
total_records = df.count()
print("Total records : ",total_records)
# Add a unique index column to the DataFrame
df_with_index = df.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())

num_loop=3
data_size_per_loop=200000
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(num_loop):
    print("start_time : ",start_time)
    start = i * data_size_per_loop
    end = (i + 1) * data_size_per_loop
    # Filter data based on index column
    paginated_df = df_with_index.filter((df_with_index["index"] >= start) & (df_with_index["index"] < end))
    paginated_records = paginated_df.count()
    print("paginated_records : ",paginated_records)
    # Filter data based on index
    paginated_data = paginated_df.filter(paginated_df.index >= start).filter(paginated_df.index < end)
    list_data = paginated_data.toJSON().collect()
    size = len(list_data)
    # Convert the list to JSON
    json_data = json.dumps(list_data)
    
    #data = paginated_data
    if size == 0:
            print("No more records for push into AWS.")
            break
    else:
        # Convert JSON data to a string
        data_payload = '\n'.join(json_data)
        end_data_range_time = time.time() - start_time
        print("Time taken to prepare aws format json data : ", end_data_range_time, " seconds")
        savefile_name= file_name+str(i)+"_"+str(size)+"_"+str(end)+".json"
        s3_client.put_object(Body=data_payload, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=savefile_name)
        end_AWS = time.time() - end_data_range_time
        print(f"data push into AWS S3. Starting records: {start} and end: {end}, size : {size}, loop nimber : {i}, time to push into AWS : {end_AWS} seconds")
```

Comment: what about just configure AWS credentials and do `df.write.format("json").mode("append").save("s3:/....")` ?

Comment: Thank you @AlexOtt for your reply.  Size of file would be large if we write 800 millions of records in one file. That's why we thought of splitting up into multiple files which is causing performance issue.

Comment: Spark will not write a single file but many files (depending on number of tasks, executors, spark partitions, etc.). In your case you simply going through the data multiple times and it's very slow, plus you have a bottleneck in form of driver to which you do the `.collect`. When you write to Spark, each task/node will write data in parallel

Comment: 800M records is not a large file, except in the special case "we use json". save to .parquet and reduce your storage and query costs

Answer (score 0):

Really, the current approach is an anti-pattern for following reasons (and you're wasting your money):

- You're doing multiple passes through the same data again & again because you need to filter the data
- You have a bottleneck in form of the driver to which you collect the data - it's only process that actually communicates with S3.

The better approach would be to use Spark itself to write data:

- Set necessary configurations to write to S3 as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/amazon-s3)
- Just do `df.write.format("json").save("s3a://<bucket>/...")`

With this you will have all your worker nodes writing to S3 in parallel. The number of files written will depend on number of workers and some other parameters.

Comment: *"current approach is an anti-pattern... and you're wasting your money"* :D, letting 'em off easy these days.

Comment: also, even with spark doing the real work, you will get burned a bit by the cost of file rename in job commit. look at the s3a committers (apache hadoop docs) or the EMR equivalent, if you use them.

Comment: we have connectivity open from DBx to S3. But when trying below line df.write.format("json").save("s3a://<bucket_name>/...")... we are getting error com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Remote host terminated the handshake: Unable to execute HTTP request: Remote host terminated the handshake

Comment: check maybe you have web proxy or something like that in between?

Answer (score 0):

Using loops over a `Dataframe` is an anti-pattern IMO as well.

Assuming:

```
df = (
  spark
  .read
  .format("json")
  .options(header='true', inferSchema='true')
  .option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")
  .load("abfss://path/product.db/table_name")
)
```

1. If `df.write.format("json").save("s3a://<bucket>/path/to/table")` produces very big and small files, then it's because the original table designers messed up their choice of partitioning column, causing hot-spots/uneven-partitions.
2. You can try `df.repartition(num_partitions).write.format("json").save("s3..")`, if you the only thing you care for is even file size and easy control over number of files.
3. Or you can think ahead of how this data would be used and come up with a good partitioning key for your target and then you could:

```py
df.repartition(num_partitions, 'id', 'sub-id').write.format("json").save("s3a://<bucket>/path/to/table")
```

4. Number 1 should give you good random distribution, if you want more custom distribution then implement your own hash function to compute the partition id for each row based on meaningful columns.

```
>>> 
>>> @udf
... def str_2_hash_code(*my_strings):
...     my_string = ''.join(sorted(filter(None, my_strings)))
...     truncated_hash = hashlib.sha1(str.encode(my_string)).digest()[-2:]
...     unsigned_hash = int.from_bytes(truncated_hash, 'big')
...     
...     return unsigned_hash
... 
>>> my_partition_columns = ['id', 'sub-id']
>>> df.withColumn('partition_col', str_2_hash_code(*my_partition_columns)).show()
>>>
```

---

You might also want to checkout:

- [DataFrame.repartition()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition)
- [DataFrameWriter.bucketBy()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.bucketBy.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.bucketBy)
- [DataFrameWriter.partitionBy()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.partitionBy.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.partitionBy)

---

PS:

> "Using loops over a `Dataframe` is an anti-pattern IMO as well."

This is putting it VERY gently. What you're doing to a `Dataframe` inside that loop is unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @kashyap for your reply. All inputs are highly appreciated, we are new here and still learning.

Basic problem we are fetching now when we are trying to connect to S3 using s3a protocol we are getting error.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
.appName("S3_Write")\
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", ACCESS_KEY_ID)\
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)\
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithmy", "SSE-KMS")\
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com")\
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket>.server-side-encryption.key", "arn:aws:kms:key")\
.config('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider')\
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("json").options(header='true', inferSchema='true').option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").load("abfss://path/table").limit(10000)

df.write.format("json").save("s3a://<bucket>/data.json")
```

***we are getting below error***

```
    shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on s3a://<bucket>/data.json: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: 
    Unable to execute HTTP request: Remote host terminated the handshake: Unable to execute HTTP request: Remote host terminated the handshake
```